# Emacs theme uses different colours in terminal

Tags: terminal, emacs, themes

I made a [theme](https://gist.github.com/mkaito/ab45709e7115850dc2b8#file-ultra-pastel-theme-el) for Emacs 24, using deftheme, based off something I generated with [4bit](http://ciembor.github.io/4bit/), with a theme structure loosely based on the built-in tango theme.

In the screenshot below, you can see `emacs -nw` on the left, and `emacs` on the right. The active [Xresources](https://gist.github.com/mkaito/ab45709e7115850dc2b8#file-xresources) file uses identical hex values.

[image: emacs deftheme]

How would I go about fixing this up?

Answer (score 0):

`emacs -nw` is limited in the colors it makes available. Your code should test using `graphic-display-p` and choose appropriate colors depending on the value.